# Conditionally allow functionality/render views in MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm using basic MVC pattern (customised version of https://github.com/panique/php-mvc) for my PHP application.

I'm not sure what is the right way to handle scenario like this:

Lets say my app will be used by 2 different companies. Each company wants to have specific functionalities. There will be some core functionalities shared by companies.
Also I need to manage user privileges in each company (admin, employee, etc.).

My goal is to have "modules" (specific functionality - dashboard, profile page, ...) and have them loaded conditionally for each company + affected by user privileges.

Also I need to somehow load different layout for each company. (Not totally different, slight changes only.)

I've googled it a bit and found stuff like ACL and Decorator, but I think they aren't what I'm looking for.

What is the best way for this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very broad question here.
I hope you know that you will need them to login and depending of the user logged in, the data you will show.

Comment: I'm a beginner with MVC, but I don't need specific code examples etc. here. I just need to be pointed the right direction :).

Comment: You are asking on where your code would be located? Or how you will determine what data to show? This is what is not clear to me.

Comment: Maybe both. What is not clear to me is, how to have one MVC application used by 2 companies. Like myapp.com will be main site. Then I wanted to have something like myapp.com/company1 and myapp.com/company2. Each company should have different database, and different "modules" which will show after login. I also wants to have these modules functionality restricted by user role in company.

Comment: Yeah broad question. If you want, reach me on my email contact@alexkvazos.com. I can help you out better.

Answer (score 0):

I assume (sorry, no time to check) this framework is really MVC-like with single point entry (bootsrtap).
Whole bussiness logic and request proccessing stays the same for each company, only config is different.

For start You need to add one domain top-level url part (main folder or subdomain), then extract it as company name/alias/id from url request ($_GET) and use it as a variable to load proper config - db entry (at least), maybe activated modules (if not stored in db), personalized view (file prefix/folder name) etc. It all comes to small .htaccess & framework enhancement in (app) config loading part (variable path). The rest is just writing full working app for one hypothetical company with all modules activated:)

Your homepage (domain only url) would serve only as a dispatcher to concrete company then (It doesn't have to be framework based - even plain html with links would do), but it would be simpler than having another common database to serve as an automatic dispatcher to other dbs (not that hard thing to do, but I'd leave it for later developement).

Comment: Is it a good idea to make subfolders for each company and put models, views, controllers folders into each one? And make f.e. 'common' folder for shared modules?

Comment: @networ - My understanding of the problem was that it's the whole Application (Models, Views and controllers) is the component that should be shared here, unless you want to write separate (different kind) apps under common domain based on particular framework.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. What I probably want to make is some custom MVC framework with some shared core components like login, admin area, etc. and then make for each company different kind of application based on it. But my goal is to have all of these apps on one server, so I want to have core of the app ('framework') in root directory and then for example have folder 'private' and in it folders: common, company1, company2 - and in each of this folders have Models, Views and Controllers folders. Then I would access it like myapp.com/company1. Is it a good scheme?

Comment: @networ - Yes. And my answer stay almost the same, but instead of config pointer variable you'll need app pointing variable (the config will be chosen by app itself).

Comment: My goal is to have easily updatable framework. That's why I thought it would be great if I make it centralised. But as I'm thinking about it now, maybe it's easier and better to have full copy of framework in each folder of company and don't worry about some special routing. But I don't know how to solve updating of f.e. login system. If I change something, I would have to manually update it in each copy of framework...

Comment: A (good) framework is sth you should rather extend (or refactor) and not change it's behavior. Extension needed by one app doesn't affect others.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not to be clear with my questions. I'll try to give example on something popular - Wordpress. So, If I want to have 10 WP sites on one server, I'll install full WP ten times in each folder (I know it have a multisite support for a while, but consider it doesn't). Then if I want to update WP I need to do it manually 10 times. Is this a way to go? Have full copy of my custom framework in each folder?

Comment: You are talking about custom sets of tightly coupled libraries not a framework (the name isn't accidental) and propably missing the whole point of OOP. I advise you to create one app based on fw - it should clear some doubts.